# Show last access time of a table in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I'm using Oracle RDBMS for database. I'm trying to clean up the database and want to know if certain tables are even used any more. I require the last accessed time of these tables to reach a conclusion.

Please note that I need the timestamp of the latest `SELECT` query. I've solutions for finding timestamp of other activities like `UPDATE`, `ALTER`, etc. I'm looking specifically for `SELECT` timestamp.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`AUDIT(traditional auditing)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/AUDIT-Traditional-Auditing.html#GUID-ADF45B07-547A-4096-8144-50241FA2D8DD):

```
AUDIT SELECT ON table_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, @lad2025 is right, I'd use `AUDIT` to find out who is accessing the tables.

To switch it on, just use:

```
AUDIT SELECT ON scott.emp  BY ACCESS;
AUDIT SELECT ON scott.dept BY ACCESS;
```

You can then see which tables are audited by querying:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS 
WHERE owner='SCOTT';

OWNER OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE SEL
SCOTT DEPT        TABLE       A/A
SCOT  EMP         TABLE       A/A
```

If somebody selects from one of the audited tables, it appears in the audit trail:

```
SELECT * FROM scott.emp;

SELECT os_username, username, obj_name, action_name, timestamp
  FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE
   AND owner = 'SCOTT' 
   AND action=3
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC;

OS_USERNAME USERNAME OBJ_NAME ACTION NAME TIMESTAMP
xxxx        yyy      EMP      SELECT      2018-05-30 08:01:07
```

To switch it off again, use:

```
NOAUDIT ALL ON scott.emp;
SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS WHERE OWNER='SCOTT';

OWNER OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE SEL
SCOTT DEPT        TABLE       A/A
```

Be cautious, though. One row is added to the audit trail for each SELECT, so watch it carefully, it can generate a lot of data very quickly.