# OCI:version 9.2 How to find out who has updated an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Is  there a way to find out who has updated an oracle table? 
I could find the date and the number of updates by executing the query

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_modifications
```

but don't know how to check the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch on auditing to see who has updated the table. See for instance the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596060/show-last-access-time-of-a-table-in-oracle-db/50597477#50597477) question.

```
AUDIT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON scott.emp BY ACCESS WHENEVER SUCCESSFUL;
```

The user is then found in the view `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`:

```
SELECT os_username, username, obj_name, action_name, timestamp
  FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE
   AND owner = 'SCOTT' 
   AND obj_name = 'EMP'
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```